# How to override my global agent to have a specific stage run on another agent in jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

i want to run two pipelines both on different agents to make both jobs run parallely. But i want one stage to execute asynchronously. I have added a global agent like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'windows' }
    stages {
        stage('Initialize Pipeline') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                printSuccess("Pipeline Started.")
                callWebhook("Running","Pipeline Started.")
            }
        }
```

this label refers to two agents (`Windows_Agent` and `Windows_2019`)...either of which will run each of the two jobs.

But i want this stage to specifically run on a single agent:

```
stage('Remove tenant URL from maintenance window Cloudfront'){  
            agent { label 'Windows_2019' }
            steps{
```

this stage picks up cloudfront distribution list and each pipeline removes a CNAME from it. this results in concurrency errors when this stage is executed parallely. Instead only this stage needs to execute on a single agent such that the other job executes when the specified agent `Windows_2019` becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

 we are selecting agent for each stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Initialize Pipeline') {
            agent { label 'windows' }
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                printSuccess("Pipeline Started.")
                callWebhook("Running","Pipeline Started.")
            }

        stage('Remove tenant URL from maintenance window Cloudfront'){  
            agent { label 'Windows_2019' }
            steps{}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya but the problem in this case is that each stage executes with either of the both agents. This means if one job has executed one stage on ```Windows_Agent``` and another one on ```Windows_2019``` then the jobs might switch agents in the next stage. That approach is not very consistent in cases where the number of jobs is greater than the number of agents. It can have unpredictable execution patterns.

Comment: why can't you have more specific labels, labels that are not shared?

Comment: because if i were to run three pipelines with two agents, the execution flow goes in an unpredictive manner. Rather than executing the first two pipelines with agent and then executing the third pipeline, it executes all three. This becomes a problem when the order is important.